# How to read system environment variable in index.html using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

**strong text**Webpack configuration is as follows :

**webpack.config.js** is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: '../public'},
            {from: '../src/fonts', to: 'fonts'},
            {from: '../src/images'}
        ]),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URL']),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {presets: ["es2015", "react"]},
                }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{loader: 'svg-react-loader'}],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|otf|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        disableHostCheck: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
};
```

What I need to achieve is to read this REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URLenvironmental variable in index.html as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//%REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URL%/analytics.js"></script>
```

Any help on this front?

**Plus we are using Bamboo to dynamically pass us per environment variables. How can we assign those variables to node variables and Use in plugin?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use interpolate-html-plugin

```
yarn add interpolate-html-plugin --dev
```

webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
      'REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URL': process.env.REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URL
    })
]
```

Then in the html file, you can use it.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//%REACT_APP_OMNITURE_URL%/analytics.js"></script>
```

More info can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpolate-html-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)? It's worked for me adding script paths. From the docs:

```
webpack.config.js

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: 'index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
This will generate a file dist/index.html containing the following

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but How will System Environment Variables are picked up in html? via env json parameter?

Comment: Plus we are using Bamboo ( this is basically CI/CD pipeline ) to dynamically pass us per environment variables. How can we assign those variables to node variables and Use in plugin?